# Decimal numbers in sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have to store numbers with many decimal places. For example: 0.000000054

If I store it in a column float data type the value is saved as: 5.4E-8

This value has to be displayed in php template with original format, how can I do it?

Would it be correct to store decimals into varchar?

Comment: One problem to store numbers as varchar is that you can't make a query to show the lowest record in your table, or the records lower than 0.5 for instance

Answer (score 1):

`0.000000054` and `5.4E-8` are both a string representation of the same float value. When converting to a string PHP just prefers to show the latter one, because it uses less characters. This way of numbering allows for much smaller/bigger numbers by storing them in the same amount of memory.

To force the output into the first type of string, use [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/number_format)

```
number_format($myFloat, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it comes:

```
$number = 0.000000054;
echo sprintf('%.9f', $number);
           //   ^---- this number indicates how many digits are shown //
```

Use this for displaying only. Its a normal thing programming-languages turn large numbers into potential-format. You can calculate with them just as with any other number.

[Manual sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)